# PHP, Mysql experience needed

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on one project, but im stopped becouse i got problem with one file or sql.
I'm not so experienced with mysql, so i come here to try find anyone who can help me to fix this.
The problem is next. I'm trying to make functionaly website about sport betting tips on this adress http://tipovi.esy.es/
Everything working, except one file.
When i login, and when i try to add TIP, it looks like this ( Picture link 1)

When i login, and when i try to add TIP, it looks like this in this picture( Picture link 2)

Now, when i need to SELECT sport, league, event i can't. It don't show nothing. Sems it need to get it from database. When i enter in database, there are's bases for League, Sport, Event and others. But something is wrong. That is my problem

The database looks like this ( Picture link 3 )

And the base for sport looks like this ( Picture link 4)

Now, maybe problem is in file create.php , i will attach the file, or screenshoot, to include everyhing, so if someone chosse to help me, will be easier like this.
I can't add more than 2 links, so i need to write like this :(

1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTNKq.png
  2 qtBCS .png
  3 CTr5z .png
  4 R58JF .png

I will be so thankful if someone can help me to fix this thing. Thanks in advance 
Ps: I can't add more links, so i will add in comment file create.php

Comment: show your create.php code here

Comment: not need show full code, you can show only specific code where you face problem

Comment: mainly what you want?

Comment: show you final code.

Comment: you submitted your code 3 times, please show code finalny

Comment: ok, i understand that clearly. `$sports->result()` php code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Select Sports field :

In your `create()` method under `Tips` controller like bellow :

```
Template::set('sports', $this->sports_model->get_tips_sports());
```

Some change your `get_tips_sports()` method in `Sports_model` like bellow :

```
function get_tips_sports()
{
    $this->db->select('sports.id, name,icon,sports.active');
    $this->db->from('sports');
    $this->db->join('events', 'events.sport_id  = sports.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('sports.active', 1);
    $this->db->group_by('sports.id');
    $this->db->order_by('display_order', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

> For Select League :

Just you change you `get_leagues_by_sport_id($id)` in League_model.php like bellow :

```
public function get_leagues_by_sport_id($id)
{
    $this->db->select('leagues.league_id, leagues.league_name, leagues.sport_id');
    $this->db->join('events', 'events.league_id  = leagues.league_id', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('leagues',array('leagues.sport_id'=>$id));

    $leagues = array();

    if($query->result())
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $league) {
            $leagues[$league->league_id] = $league->league_name;
        }
        return $leagues;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```